# Create Exception on Mime filtering on squid

Tags: ubuntu, mime, squid

I have a server with the operating system Ubuntu 12:04 LTS version.
I also paired the squid version 3.1.19 on my server. with the client about 30 units.

to prevent my clients to download any files and streaming, I use 
`acl xxx rep_mime_type application/octet-stream` during limited hours. Of course with `http_reply_access deny xxx`.

But I see that the anti-virus update (average client using avast) on squid logs to participate blocked. the question is, how is that files of a particular site made ​​an exception.

Thanks for the advice